# Cross tab Pivot in TSQLwith group by and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, crosstab

i have a cros tab query in MS Access which i want to replicate in T-SQL, 
T-SQL table '#tmpZSPO_DMD' has Part,Location, Qty,FiscalMonthPeriod. and when i run, the data looks like below.

```
Part LOCATION   Qty FiscalMonthPeriod
123 4040_0086       1        CON00
123 4040_0086       1   CON00
123 4200_0010       1   CON00
123 2070_0060       2   CON01
123 2080_0061      1    CON01
123 4040_0070      1    CON02
123 4040_0070      2    CON02
123 4040_0086      1    CON02
123 2020_0060      2    CON03
123 2020_0064      1    CON03
123 2040_0060      1    CON03
123 4040_0061      1    CON03
123 4040_0061      1    CON03
123 4040_0069      1    CON03
123 4040_0070      1    CON03
```

I am looking to achieve the below result.

```
Part    LOCATION    CON00   CON01   CON02   CON03
123 2020_0060                                2
123 2020_0064                                1
123 2040_0060                                1
123 2070_0060                2      
123 2080_0061                1      
123 4040_0061                                 2
123 4040_0069                                 1
123 4040_0070                        3        1
123 4040_0086        2               1  
123 4200_0010        1
```

Comment: I think , PIVOT is one of the most duplicated topic in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple PIVOT will do the job.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Part, LOCATION, Qty, FiscalMonthPeriod
    FROM @Table
) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR FiscalMonthPeriod IN ([CON00], [CON01], [CON02], [CON03])
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT tm.PART, tm.Location,
   SUM(IIF(tm.FiscalMonthPeriod= 'CON00', [Sum], NULL)) As CON00,
   SUM(IIF(tm.FiscalMonthPeriod= 'CON01', [Sum], NULL)) As CON01,
   SUM(IIF(tm.FiscalMonthPeriod= 'CON02', [Sum], NULL)) As CON02,
   SUM(IIF(tm.FiscalMonthPeriod= 'CON03', [Sum], NULL)) As CON03
     FROM #tmpZSPO_DMD tm
     GROUP BY tm.PART, tm.Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Part
      ,LOCATION
      ,ISNULL(CON00 , 0) AS CON00
      ,ISNULL(CON01 , 0) AS CON01
      ,ISNULL(CON02 , 0) AS CON02
      ,ISNULL(CON03 , 0) AS CON03
FROM tablename T 
  PIVOT (SUM(Qty)
         FOR FiscalMonthPeriod
         IN(CON00 , CON01, CON02, CON03)
         )p
```